# Drop rows where meet criteria of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `df`

```
   a       b  
0  str1    0
1  str2   .8
2  str3   .4
3  str4   .1
```

I am iterating through this dataframe.  (which i know is not the most efficient way).

I want to drop all rows where `b>.7`.  This is iterating in a loop, so i want to drop from the same dataframe.

The append has syntax like this:

```
new_df = new_df.append(df[df['a']>.7],ignore_index= 'True')
```

Can I do something similar with the drop?

```
df.drop(df[df['a']>.7])
```

I get the error:
"`....  not found in axis`"

The expected result is `df` as:

```
   a       b  
0  str1    0
2  str3   .4
3  str4   .1
```

Comment: You may want to read about boolean indexing

Comment: `df[df['b']<0.7]`

Comment: `df[~df['b'].gt(0.7)]`

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. and there are multiple ways using Boolean indexing:

1) Retain rows where b is less than or equal to 7

```
df = df[df.b<=0.7]
```

2) Use .loc for the same condition

```
df = df.loc[df.b<=0.7]
```

3) Filter out rows which are greater than 0.7

```
df=df[~df.b>0.7]
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same, 3 is slightly different, if the column has `nan`.